# Trouble with Task.WhenAny

Tags: c#, .net, server, async-await

I am using .NET framework to create a server, which listens on two ports on localhost.  It is a simple console application.

It works when I keep connecting to one of the ports, but after I connect to first, another does not respond.  First still is alive.

Here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress hostIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses("127.0.0.1")[0];
        List<TcpListener> listeners = new List<TcpListener>()
        {
            new TcpListener(hostIP, 6060),
            new TcpListener(hostIP, 6061)
        };
        foreach (TcpListener listener in listeners)
        {
            listener.Start();
        }
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Socket socket = AcceptAnyConnection(listeners).Result;
                NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                //stream.Close();
                socket.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (TcpListener listener in listeners)
            {
                listener.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task<Socket> AcceptAnyConnection(List<TcpListener> listeners)
    {
        List<Task<Socket>> tasks = new List<Task<Socket>>();
        foreach (TcpListener listener in listeners)
        {
            tasks.Add(AcceptConnection(listener));
        }
        Task<Socket> completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        return await completedTask;
    }
    private static async Task<Socket> AcceptConnection(TcpListener listener)
    {
        Socket socket = await listener.AcceptSocketAsync();
        return socket;
    }
```

await Task.WhenAny() blocks if I connect to another port.

I must be doing something wrong, but I am not sure what.

BTW, I did try the same with .NET Core console application, and it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: This is pretty complex, but if you dont use `.Result` but `await`, it will work... make your main function an async Task.

Comment: One problem is that every time a listener gets a new connection, you will call `AcceptSocketAsync` on all listeners (and throw away the previous incomplete Task from the last time you called it). Instead, you probably want to maintain a single `List<Task<Socket>>`, and every time one of them completes, remove that from the list, call `AcceptSocketAsync` on the listener whose task completed, and put the new task in the list

Comment: Archie, while both above answers are correct, i suggest you dig into event pattern here, you could make each listener to work into a separated thread and whenever you find a connection or a message fire up an event to another layer of your application and you wont be having any problem like this

Comment: You absolutely must not use `Result` on any task that you do not know to be complete; that makes your asynchronous workflow into a synchronous workflow, which can then deadlock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest refactoring your code to something like this, and taking it from there. That is, run an infinite loop for each listener. That avoids problems with making sure that you only call `AcceptTcpClientAsync` once at a time for each client.

(Note there's no code to actually stop the listeners. Also completely untested - please use it only as an indication of the sort of approach to take)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IPAddress hostIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses("127.0.0.1")[0];
    List<TcpListener> listeners = new List<TcpListener>()
    {
        new TcpListener(hostIP, 6060),
        new TcpListener(hostIP, 6061)
    };

    var listenerTasks = listeners.Select(x => RunTcpListener(x)).ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(listenerTasks);
}

private static async Task RunTcpListener(TcpListener listener)
{
    listener.Start();

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            using (var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync())
            {
                var stream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello canton7!  Your code did not work for me by some reason, but your earlier suggestion to take the list of tasks out of infinite loop - did.  I will post my updated code below...  Thanks!

Comment: @Archie I just tried this code, verbatim, and it worked fine. What exactly do you mean by "did not work for me"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, after I followed a suggestion by canton7 to move the task list outside of loop and move add and remove tasks "as we go". Probably, I will have to look at it to clean it up, but the idea works:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress hostIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses("127.0.0.1")[0];
        List<TcpListener> listeners = new List<TcpListener>()
        {
            new TcpListener(hostIP, 6060),
            new TcpListener(hostIP, 6061)
        };
        ProcessConnections(listeners).Wait();
    }

    private async static Task SendData(Socket socket)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        socket.Close();
    }

    private static async Task ProcessConnections(List<TcpListener> listeners)
    {
        foreach (TcpListener listener in listeners)
        {
            listener.Start();
        }
        try
        { 
            List<Task<Socket>> tasks = new List<Task<Socket>>();
            foreach (TcpListener listener in listeners)
            {
                tasks.Add(AcceptConnection(listener));
            }
            while (true)
            {
                int i = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());
                Socket socket = await tasks[i];
                await SendData(socket);
                tasks.RemoveAt(i);
                tasks.Insert(i, AcceptConnection(listeners[i]));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (TcpListener listener in listeners)
            {
                listener.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
    private static async Task<Socket> AcceptConnection(TcpListener listener)
    {
        Socket socket = await listener.AcceptSocketAsync();
        return socket;
    }
```

Comment: (No need to `await tasks[i]` -- you know it's already completed, so you can just do `tasks[i].Result`)